Inconsistent Timestamps and Missing Details in Firestore Upon User Login and Logout
I'm implementing a user authentication and logging system in my Flutter application using Firebase Firestore. However, I've encountered two primary issues that I need help resolving:
Timestamps Issue:
When a user logs in, the login timestamp recorded in Firestore matches exactly with the logout timestamp when the user logs out. I expect them to be different and accurately reflect the times of these respective actions. How can I ensure that the logout timestamp captures the correct time distinct from the login timestamp?
Details Update Issue:
Upon user login or logout, I also intend to update additional details in Firestore such as Compoundlocation, ID, and full name. However, these details sometimes do not get fully updated or are missing in my Firestore table. What could be causing this issue, and how can I ensure all details are consistently updated upon user login or logout?
Here’s an excerpt of my relevant code for handling user authentication, login/logout actions, and Firestore updates:
// Example code snippet showing login and logout implementation
void _logout() async {
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  if (user != null) {
    final userId = user.uid;
    final userDetails = await getUserDetails(userId);

    final userDocRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('signing').doc(userId);

    // Get the login timestamp from user details
    final loginTimestamp = userDetails['login'];

    // Log logout time with user details and login timestamp
    await userDocRef.update({
      "authActivity": FieldValue.arrayUnion([
        {
          "action": "logout",
          "timestamp": loginTimestamp, // Use the captured login timestamp for logout
          'FullName': userDetails['FullName'],
          'ID': userDetails['ID'],
          'compound': userDetails['compound'],
        }
      ])
    });

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, Signin.screenroute, (route) => false);
  }
}


I’m using Flutter with Firebase Firestore for my backend.
I've ensured that Firestore security rules allow these operations, and there are no errors reported in the Firebase console.
I expect the logout timestamp to accurately reflect the time when the user logs out, distinct from the login timestamp.
I expect all details (Compoundlocation, ID, full name) to be fully updated and consistent in Firestore upon user login or logout.I’ve attempted to use FieldValue.serverTimestamp() for both login and logout timestamps, but they consistently match.
I’ve checked my Firestore rules and ensured that the required fields are correctly specified for updates.

"How can I ensure that the logout timestamp captures the correct time distinct from the login timestamp?" Er, you have explicit comments "// Log logout time with user details and login timestamp" and "// Use the captured login timestamp for logout".  If you don't want the logout timestamp to equal the login timestamp, then just stop using timestamp for both.  Use DateTime.now().toUtc() and convert it to your appropriate format.

thanks, but my code give me the same result

And what is your  new code?
